# How to load activty while Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, html, android-layout

I've got an viewpager which contains 7 slides. But the content of the slides is HTML, so i want to load the data of the HTML in a splashscreen and after that i want to show the content. My content gets inflatet in the instantiateItem Method of my activity.

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        HTMLPre preparer = new HTMLPre();

        String font = "SourceSansPro-Regular";


        View one = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);


        WebView header_1_a = (WebView) one.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Aktien1_header),header_1_a,font);
        ImageView image_1_a = (ImageView) one.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_kap01_01);
        WebView text_1_a = (WebView) one.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien1), text_1_a,font);

        View two = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);


        header_1_a = (WebView) two.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Aktien2_header),header_1_a,font);
        image_1_a = (ImageView) two.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture_kap01_01);
        text_1_a = (WebView) two.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien2), text_1_a,font);


        View three = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);

        header_1_a = (WebView) three.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Aktien3_header), header_1_a,font);
        image_1_a = (ImageView) three.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.boerse_antwerpen);
        text_1_a = (WebView) three.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien3), text_1_a,font);


        View four = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);

        header_1_a = (WebView) four.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Aktien4_header), header_1_a,font);
        image_1_a = (ImageView) four.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_a_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.parketthandel);
        text_1_a = (WebView) four.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien4), text_1_a,font);



        View five = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_c, container, false);

        image_1_a = (ImageView) five.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_c_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.parketthandel);
        text_1_a = (WebView) five.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_c_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien5), text_1_a,font);




        View six = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_c, container, false);

        image_1_a = (ImageView) six.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_c_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.parketthandel);
        text_1_a = (WebView) six.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_c_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien6), text_1_a,font);


        View seven = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_c, container, false);

        image_1_a = (ImageView) seven.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_c_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.parketthandel);
        text_1_a = (WebView) seven.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_c_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien7), text_1_a,font);

        View eigth = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_c, container, false);

        image_1_a = (ImageView) eigth.findViewById(R.id.image_slide_type_c_1);
        image_1_a.setImageResource(R.drawable.seewegevoc);
        text_1_a = (WebView) eigth.findViewById(R.id.text_slide_type_c_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentText(getString(R.string.Aktien8), text_1_a,font);



        View nine = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.startquiz_layout, container, false);
        View viewarr[] = {one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eigth, nine};
        container.addView(viewarr[position]);


        return viewarr[position];

    }
```

So now i want to load the action which is done in this activty while splashscreen is loading. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: There's no `instatiateItem` method of the `Activity` - you're probably referring to the method of the `PagerAdapter`?
A solution for this would be to put a view on top of the `ViewPager` in your `Activity`'s XML layout and hide the `ViewPager` until the load is done. The view would be your splashscreen. The splashscreen could basically just be a view filling the screen and a progressbar on top of this view.

Comment: but how can i set a view on top of my viewpager temporary until it the view pager elements are loaded? and how knows the other view when the viewpager is finished? is there anything like setconten in my activity class of my view pager, which i would add my loadscreen view?

Comment: In your `Activity`'s XML you can add a `View` on top of the `ViewPager`, then you can add a listener for when you're code (`HTMLPre`) is done loading the websites. The listener could be your `Activity` and when the load is done, you hide the `View` you've put on top of the `ViewPager`.

Comment: @Darwind can you give me a example how i load a view like a image or something over the ViewPager?    You see my current code as a new answer.

Comment: I've got a relative layout which contains the view pager. But when i change the background of the relativelayout it doesn't overlay the content of the slides layouts...

Comment: I've added my full sample project to the answer now. Have a look at it. I've tried to "mimic" how you load data and it still seems to work nicely for me.

Answer (score 1):

So for the sake of simplicity, I created a small sample app showing how this could be created.

Instead of copy-pasting all the code in here I created a Gist, that you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/darwind/ed153ff267413d21f74203d6f5e1d200).

Please be aware that this code is just an example and doesn't take care of any error handling and such and it's by no means optimised to taking care of a lot of `WebView`s for instance.

I know it doesn't exactly use your code, but I don't know what a `HTMLPre` is and I'm just using the default way of loading websites in the `WebView`.

**EDIT:** Added the whole Git repository, so it's possible to run the full sample project - find it [here](https://github.com/darwind/LoadingView).